# Making Chrome headless undetectable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to follow this guide to make Chrome headless undetectable.

https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

The problem is, it seems to involve using Javascript and running scripts through the command prompt. I'm hoping to create an executable Python script with Selenium that I could use on multiple computers without manually setting anything up through command lines. I know I can reference Javascript files in Python, but this guide uses Javascript and command lines for everything and I can't figure out how to apply it to my Python project.

Is there a way to make Chrome headless undetectable in a more portable way when using Python and Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by using options :

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=str(BASE_DIR / "webdrivers" / "chromedriver"),
        options=chrome_options,
    )
```

Reference : [Chrome Headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)